# Microsoft Login Failing:AADSTS70001: Application with identifier was not found in the directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am using Microsoft Login on our website. It was working fine some time back. However, it started failing recently. I am getting above mentioned error. It is a Live SDK App. However, I have another Converged app for the development testing of same website. The converged app is working fine. The Live SDK app has a different ID too.

The web app is a .net core application. I am standard authentication package for the MS login.

[This post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/f494fb5b-cbdd-42c8-9d0f-d44e3c9ed44e/aadsts70001-application-with-identifier-was-not-found?forum=WindowsAzureAD) says I need to create an Azure Directory for the failing app. However, I don't remember doing it working the working app either. Where am I doing wrong?

The body of the response is added below:

```
Body: {
    "error": "unauthorized_client",
    "error_description": "AADSTS70001: Application with identifier '000000004417E431' was not found in the directory 9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad\r\nTrace ID: fc45d396-ba9d-4136-95a4-48dc5b2c0a00\r\nCorrelation ID: 92be473b-b89c-440f-aa39-68de422770fa\r\nTimestamp: 2017-08-05 14:58:24Z",
    "error_codes": [70001],
    "timestamp": "2017-08-05 14:58:24Z",
    "trace_id": "fc45d396-ba9d-4136-95a4-48dc5b2c0a00",
    "correlation_id": "92be473b-b89c-440f-aa39-68de422770fa"
};
```

Comment: can you share the specific error message? It seems like you removed the "identifier"

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi Added complete message.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem here is that you are trying to use Azure Active Directory authentication protocols to authenticate a Live SDK application. **This will not work.**

As you mentioned in your post, your converged application is working fine... this is because converged applications, also known as V2 Applications are special in that they support both Azure Active Directory and Microsoft Accounts natively. V2 applications try to solve the very problem you are finding here, which is the need to set up two different authentication pathways for both AAD and MSA users.

Learn more about V2 applications here: [Sign-in Microsoft Account & Azure AD users in a single app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview)